# Robot framework: Assigning variables from a dictionary

Tags: robotframework

I have a scenario in which I would have to read from a dictionary and create variables with key as the variable name and value as the variable's value.

For example, if "hello": "world" is a dictionary item, then I have to set hello = world. This variable also needs to be later called in a test case. I tried to achieve this via below method but not sure if it has the right syntax and anyway it fails with `No keyword with name '${$k}}  found` error.

Can anyone let me know if this can be done?

```
*** Keywords ***
Spin Variables
    ${items}=    get dictionary items   ${arg}
    :For  ${k}  ${v}  IN  @{items}
    \   ${${k}}=  set variable  ${v}
```

Comment: I dont excatly undertand what you wish to do here. As you iterating a list, the varible you are assigning to a value will always get the last value of the list. 
Why dont you acessing the elements of the dictionary by its `key`?

Like this: 


`Get Me a Dictionary
${Dictionary}= Create Dictionary  key1=Hello  key2=Word`
[Return]  ${Dictionary}

$(MyDic}=  Get Me a Dictionary
$Variable1=  Set Variable  ${MyDic['key1']}
Log  ${Variable1}  #putputs -- Hello`

Comment: @RichardZilahi The requirement is to read a csv file, find the row that matches a particular value and create variables with column headers as variable name and the respective entries as value for that variable. I've done the parsing part in Python, but I'm new to robot. 
For more clarity, 

_Place_,_Name_,_Code_
_CH_|_Anon_|_DEV_
_CH_,_Anon1_,|_OPS_
_CH_,_Anon2_,_NETOPS_
_DL_,_Anon3_,_DEV_

If I read this CSV and look for Anon2, I must return ${Place} = CH, ${Name} = Anon2 and ${Code} = NETOPS. This will be later called in a test case.